# Can I anmeldung with limited time rentals in Germany?

Tags: germany

Suppose I rent a monteur zimmer (time restricted rental), eg: can I use that to do anmeldung?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably *required* to do so unless you have another registered place of residene within Germany.

Details depend on the contract and if the landlord is acting as a *Beherberungsstätte*. The safest solution would be to attempt to register. If the municipal authorities accept it, you are registered, and if not, you can say in good faith that they told you it was unnecessary.

Comment: Monteurzimmern is used for sleeping, so yes you are required to register. See [§20 Definition of residence - Federal Act on Registration](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0212) *A residence as defined in this Act is any closed space **used for living or sleeping**. ...*. and [Meldepflicht - Deutsche Immobilien und Monteurzimmer GmbH](https://monteurzimmer.immo/meldepflicht/) *Registration requirement for workers' rooms Registration and deregistration at the residents' registration office is mandatory!*

Comment: @MarkJohnson, exceptions might apply if the room is legally run as a hotel, and the operator has sufficient ID e.g. through a credit card payment. Or if the OP has another residence in Germany and lives in the room for just a few weeks.

Comment: The OP has stated that it is a monteurzimmer and not a hotel. See my comment in gerrit answer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, you can find other portals advertising rooms in hotels or vacation cottages as *Monteurzimmer* -- basically furnished rooms with low price for low comforts.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can use *any* address for Anmeldung.  The only requirement is that the host provides you with a *Wohnungsgeberbestätigung*, that you have a right to reside in Germany, and that you are actually resident at the address.

However, some time-restricted rentals might not be willing to provide a *Wohnungsgeberbestätigung*.  They might not want to deal with the paperwork, they might not want the authorities to know they are renting out property, or they might have another reason. For example, hotels typically do not offer a *Wohnungsgeberbestätigung*.  If the ability to register is important for you, contact the host in advance and ask if they are willing to provide a *Wohnungsgeberbestätigung*.

Comment: For periods up to 6 months, hotels are not required to issue a Wohnungsgeberbestätigung since they use a simplified registration. [§29 - Special registration requirement for commercial accommodations](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0274)